# Calculate difference between adjacent columns in pandas dataframe and create new column whose difference is > 2 , this new column should have count

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a data frame with Acct_ID, and cycle_delq_01 to cycle_delq_12  variables:

[image]

Problem: I want to calculate difference of all cycle delinquency variable example below:

```
cycle_delq_02 - cycle_delq_01 >= 2
cycle_delq_03 - cycle_delq_2 >=2
cycle_delq_04 - cycle_delq_3 >= 2
        
cycle_delq_12 - cycle_delq_11 >= 2
```

While checking difference if any of the condition is satisfied then count = count+1( New column should be created)

Answer (score 2):

`diff` and `sum` along the required axis:

```
df["Count"] = df.filter(like="CYC_DELQ").diff(axis=1).ge(2).sum(1)

>>> df
   CYC_DELQ_01  CYC_DELQ_02  CYC_DELQ_03  ...  CYC_DELQ_12   ID  Count
0            0            1            4  ...            3  123      2
1            0            0            0  ...            0  456      2
2            4            3            0  ...            0  345      1

[3 rows x 14 columns]
```